# How can I add a guard to a JPA manyToMany join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My testing app for JPA tracks the number of pubs a user has visited in my town. I have this on the user object

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
private List<Pub> visited;
```

And the other side on the pub object

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    joinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "pubid"),
inverseJoinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "userid"))
protected Set<User> users;
```

However, I've updated the pub table with a column indicating that the pub has been closed. I only want the the user's visited List to contain active pubs so the question is

**How can I conditionally join these objects so that only pubs that pass a test (e.g. table.closed=false) will be put in the user's visited list?**

I'm using hibernate and postgres underneath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved this for the time being using the Hibernate specific @Where annotation. I just required an extra annotation on the user's pub collection like so:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
@Where(clause="closed='false'")
private List<Pub> visited;
```

Of course I'm now locked in to Hibernate, which is not a huge problem for this project, but if anyone has a generic JPA solution I'd love to hear it.

Comment: +1 Cool, good to know that there is a clean way, even considering the lock-in.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve, or rather simulate what you want, but unfortunately no really clean one.

You can use a `@PostLoad` method, either in the User entity itself, or in a dedicated listener (annotate your entity with `@EntityListeners(YourFilter.class)` to configure the listener.). In this method, you can filter the entities the way you want them.

The major problem with this approach is that when you persist/merge, the changes made by the filter will be persisted as well.

This can be avoided - you can have a separate, transient list to hold the filtered pubs in addition to the original persistent one. Or you could leave the PostLoad filtering be and simply filter in the getter. This may sound dirty, but the listener approach is dirty in disguise.

Comment: Sounds feasible, but surely there's a way I can get this to happen at query level? In plain SQL this would just be an additional where condition. Is it possible to replace the join query generated by the @ManyToMany annotation with a custom query perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subclassing to create a pure JPA solution:

- Use "closed" field as @DiscriminatorColumn on Pub.
- Create a new Class "OpenPubs" and use the "false" as @DiscriminatorValue
- Map "visited" to the Subclass "OpenPubs"